# Combinatorics Basics

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Suppose you have 20 objects. Three objects are special, and you want them to remain together. You split the objects into two groups of 10 uniformly at random. What is the probability that the three objects remain together?

My work:

In total there are

$$\frac{20!}{10!10!2}$$ ways to separate the objects.

but by wanting 3 on the same team, we can do this in $$\frac{17!}{7!10!2}$$ ways, since we can choose our three special objects in any order, and then must divide the remaining 17.

Is this correct?

**Edit**

I am being told that it is actually $18$ choose $8$, since if we treat the group of 3 as a single object, then we have 18 objects. Is this true?

To clarify the question, let us say that you and two friends are playing football and want to be on the same team. The teams are split at random, what is the probability that you end up on the same team? Moreover, the teams are split 10 at a time.

Comment: Are the three "special" objects predetermined, or do you choose which 3 objects are special?

Comment: @Useless I guess they are predetermined

Comment: I think it is pretty correct with a little mistake. The answer must have been $$\binom {2}{1} \cdot \frac {17!}{7!10!}$$. Let the two groups be A and B.  First we select the group in which we place the special pair. And then form groups of 7 and 10 from remaining 17 objects.  Moreover there is no need of "2" in the denominator in this case.

Comment: Hey may I ask why you're dividing by 2 ?

Comment: My guess is that OP assumes ordering of the groups doesn't matter: i.e. breaking them into Group 1: {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10} and Group 2: {11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20} is the same as breaking them into Group 1: {11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20} and then  Group 2: {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}.

Comment: Then there is no need of the 3! even. I guess the OP must've clarified what actually his question is

Comment: @Useless I stated the reason below my answer.  If the ordering of groups matters. Then I just named them A and B.  And then selected any one of them for the special pair to place

Comment: Moreover I have doubt whether we are draw all 10 balls at the same time.  Or we just draw balls one by one and then place in their respective groups

Comment: My way of thinking of the problem would have been to first assume without loss of generality that the objects are labeled $1,2,3,\dots,20$ and the special objects are $1,2,3$ and to look at the nine objects in the same group as object $1$.  There are $\binom{19}{9}$ equally likely ways in which we choose the remaining objects in the first object's group, and there are $\binom{17}{7}$ ways that they include the other special objects, giving a probability of $\frac{\binom{17}{7}}{\binom{19}{9}} = \frac{4}{19}$

Comment: @Manthanein  The problem does not say that the groups are labeled.  Division by $2$ is correct.

Answer (score 1):

We convert this problem to the following:

> An urn consists of 20 balls among those 3 are special. We draw at random 10 balls out of the urn. What is the probability of choosing either all the special balls or none of them?

The probability of drawing out all the special balls is$$P_1=\dfrac{\binom{3}{3}\binom{17}{7}}{\binom{20}{10}}$$and the probability of drawing out no special ball is $$P_2=\dfrac{\binom{3}{0}\binom{17}{10}}{\binom{20}{10}}$$therefore the general probability attains by merging the two cases$$P=P_1+P_2=2\dfrac{\binom{17}{7}}{\binom{20}{10}}$$